# How can you put up the blinders and forget 1000+ years of animus with Custom Filters?

Tags: discussion

In the interest of making this [a less fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/) easier to moderate site, I'd encourage every one to come up with some custom filters to help narrow down things you're actually interested in any avoid things that might result in holy wars.  (not that we've had these recently)

But, check out [Custom Filters release announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330326/custom-filters-release-announcement?cb=1) on meta stackexchange (it's also on the right nav currently on the main site).

I'd like to see what other people come up with for the best custom filters in the answers to this question.

---

One annoyance I have with this feature (and if someone else wants to bring it up as a feature request, I'd get behind it too) is that there's no grouping in here, so don't expect parentheses to work)

Answer (score 1):

#### Don't rock the boat

- Filter by: None
- Sorted by: Recent Activity
- Tagged with: [noah](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noah) [flood-of-noah](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flood-of-noah) [ark-of-noah](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ark-of-noah)